# Templates and casting

Tags: c++, templates

I created a matrix class with templates:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,"");

public:
    Matrix(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols);
    Matrix(size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols, const T& value);

    // Functions

    // Operators
Matrix<T>& operator*=(const T& value)

private:
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

I created the following two (external) operators to multiply my matrix with a number:

```
// Inner operator used by the externals ones
template <typename T>
inline Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*=(const T& value)
{
    for(size_t i(0); i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] *= value;
    }

    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
inline Matrix<T> operator*(const T& value, const Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    Matrix<T> tmp(matrix);

    return tmp *= value;
}

template <typename T>
inline Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& matrix, const T& value)
{
    return value * matrix;
}
```

The problem is that if I declared the matrix as a double, I can multiply the matrix only by doubles and so on...

```
Matrix<double> m1(3,3,1.);

5. * m1; // Works
5 * m1; // Doesn't work (5 is an int and not a double)
```

How can I fix this behave? It is possible to let doubles be multiplied by others arithmetic types?

Comment: I removed the "casting" tag.  Conversion is when a value of one type is changed to a different type.  Casting is when you tell the compiler to do a conversion.  Here you're looking for an implicit conversion, which is not a cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just allow two parameters to your templated free functions and member functions.

For example:

```
template <typename T> class Matrix {
  /* ... */
  template <typename U>
  inline Matrix<T>& operator*=(const U& value)
  {
    for(size_t i(0); i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] *= value;
    }

    return *this;
  }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
inline Matrix<T> operator*(const U& value, const Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    Matrix<T> tmp(matrix);

    return tmp *= value;
}
```

This will trigger compiletime errors if you try to multiply your Matrix with something nonsensical, that is, if `T*U` is undefined.

Comment: The member function doesn't need this change to help template argument deduction.  But there might be other reasons to do it anyway.

Comment: @aschepler: What change? The only change I'm aware of introducing is templating the type of the parameter, and you need this, to allow it to accept arbitrary types. Are you suggesting to check whether `T*U` is allowed using SFINAE?

Comment: I only meant that the original code does allow `m1 *= 5;`, using the implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Declare the function in the Matrix class as

```
template <typename T> 
class Matrix 
{
public:
    /* ... */
    template <typename S> 
    inline Matrix & operator*=( const S & value );
    /* ... */
};
```

The definition looks like

```
template <typename T>
template <typename S>
inline Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator*=(const S& value)
{
    for(size_t i(0); i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        data[i] *= value;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

for the member function. You need to write `template` twice. A bit odd, but that's C++ syntax.

In case of the free functions you can write

```
template <typename T, typename S>
inline Matrix<T> operator*(const S& value, const Matrix<T> &mat)
{
    Matrix<T> tmp(mat);

    return tmp *= value;
}
```

Comment: Why I have to split the template definition if it is a member function while I can use a single template definition with two parameters if it is a non-member function?

Comment: That's one of the odd syntax rules of C++. I guess this is introduced, because you write `template` twice in the declaration too. Once for the class (`T`) and once for the function parameters themselves (`S`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are seeing is that template type deduction requires a perfect match of all of the deduced types. In your case you have a template that takes a single type argument `T` that is both the scalar and the matrix types. When the compilers sees the operation: `5 * m1`, it deduces `T == int` for the first argument but `T == double` for the second argument, and type deduction fails.

There are multiple approaches around this, as it has been suggested, you can add a second template argument:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
Matrix<T> operator*( Matrix<T> m, S scalar ) {
   return m*=scalar;
}
```

[Note: both arguments by value, the second one because for arithmetic types it is more efficient and idiomatic to pass by value; the first one because by moving the copy to the interface of the function you allow the compiler to elide copies]. This approach is simple, but will generate one `operator*` for each combination of `S` and `T` in the program, even though the actual multiplication in `operator*=` is always performed on `T`.

Another approach would be to fix the type of the `scalar` that you want to multiply by, for example, make it `double`, generating only one `operator*` per `T` type that is multiplied:

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T> operator*( Matrix<T> m, double scalar ) {
   return m*=scalar;
}
```

In this approach there is a single `operator*`, the one taking a `double` as argument. As in the previous example, it might require two type conversions on the scalar (say you multiply `Matrix<int>` by `5`, it will then convert `5` into a `double`, which will then be converted back to `int` to match the signature of `operator*=`.

The third approach is to create a non-templated function that takes your `Matrix` and another argument of the same type. This will be the closest to your original code, with the slight advantage that not being a template, it will allow conversions for the scalar argument. Theoretically you could define all such functions yourself manually:

```
Matrix<int>    operator*( Matrix<int>,    int ) { ... }
Matrix<double> operator*( Matrix<double>, double ) { ... }
```

But this becomes a maintenance problem very easily. Luckily, there is a feature in the language that allows for the definition of all those non-template functions *generically*. Although the syntax might not be the most natural. You just need to *declare* the free function as a friend of your template, and *define* it *inside* the class template definition:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
// ...
   friend Matrix operator*( Matrix m, T scalar ) { return m*=scalar; }
};
```

As we are inside the class template `Matrix`, we can use `Matrix` (without arguments) to refer to the current instantiation (`Matrix<int>`, `Matrix<double`...) [This might not seem obviously important, but it is, it is important to realize when `Matrix` refers to the template, and when it refers to the class generated from the template]. The second argument to the function is `T`. Again, this is not the generic `T` of the class template, but the current instantiating type (`int`, `double`...).

The language allows for the definition of a `friend` function inside the class that has the declaration, and that will *define* the function at namespace level, although the declaration will only be found through Argument Dependent Lookup.

Whenever you instantiate a particular instance of your template (say `Matrix<int>`) and call the operator, the compiler will generate the free function for you. Because the function is not templated, it will allow conversions on the arguments, and thus for `Matrix<int> m` it will allow you to call `m * 5.` by converting `5.` into an `int`.

Comment: _This approach is simple, but will generate one operator* for each combination of S and T in the program, even though the actual multiplication in operator*= is always performed on T._ This is a problem? The generation of each combination of S and T will slow only the compilation or is also a problem in runtime?

Comment: @R.M.: It is not necessarily bad, and in this particular case, where the actual function is just a forwarder it should not affect much, but say that you implemented `operator*` directly (no forwarding), then for each combination of `S` and `T` the compiler will have to generate the function, which means that there would be one implementation in the binary for each combination, and the binary would be larger. I am tempted to say that a larger binary has higher chances for cache-misses in the instruction cache, but note that this would not be noticeable in most cases.